NetCDF data of freshwater input into the North Atlantic
Is there a NetCDF database that simulates the freshwater input around Greenland? Ideally, a temporal resolution should also be available. That would help me a lot.

a couple of sites you can take a look at http://polarportal.dk/en/home/ and http://nsidc.org/arcticseaicenews/

Thank you however I did not finde the mentioned data (for shure I´m blind in this aspect :))

i hope i am wrong but i do not think there is good estimates for the water exiting from below the ice in the fjords,it is fairly easy to measure the runoff via the rivers and streams but the runoff from below the ice is a lot harder to measure.

Haha Thank you. However so you know If there are any estimations how much ice ist losst during e.g. one year in which Region?
